# jquery insertafter multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, insertafter

I have a text form field. It can be cloned/duplicated. It generates name tag like `user[name][1][1],user[name][2][1],user[name][3][1] etc`...

I want to append a link next to that text fields using jquery. I tried like this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('<a href="#">Example link</a>').insertAfter('input[name="user\[name\]\[\]\[\]"]')
});
</script>
```

But its not working. Can anyone help me?. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the jQuery selector docs, special characters need to be escaped with double backslash. For all of the elements at once you can use the `startsWith` selector and do:

```
$('input[name^="user\\[name\\]"]');
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dpJZE/2/

API selector docs:  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Read top paragraph regarding escaping

Comment: Hello mate, But its not working when i duplicate the fields. Can you tell me whats wrong?